# 'No matching function call' for subclass/superclass

Tags: c++, subclass, superclass

I'm getting a 'no matching function call' error that I can't figure out how to get rid of, and it seems to have to do with my subclass not being recognized as the superclass.  I have a superclass Geometry with a subclass Cube, declared as:

```
class Cube : public Geometry {
    //code
    Intersection intersect(const Ray& ray_in, bool& intersected) const;
};
```

and Cube has a method to return an Intersection:

```
Intersection Cube::intersect(const Ray& ray_in, bool& intersected) const {
    // code
    return Intersection(point, normal, t_near, this);   //point and normal are vec4, t_near is double
}
```

I have an Intersection constructor:

```
Intersection(const glm::vec4& _point, const glm::vec4& _normal, Geometry* _geometry, const double _t);
```

but when I try to compile, the return line in my Cube::intersect method gives the error:

```
no matching function for call to 'Intersection::Intersection(glm::vec4&, glm::vec4&, float&, const Cube*)'
   return Intersection(point, normal, t_near, this);
                                                  ^
```

Why would it not recognize that Cube is a subclass of Geometry and attempt to call the correct Intersection constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't appear to have anything to do with subclasses. The constructor's parameters are simply wrong:

```
return Intersection(point, normal, t_near, this);
```

It's not clear what `t_near` is, but it's likely to be a `double`. You're passing a `double` for the third parameter to the constructor, and `this` as the fourth parameter to the constructor, which obviously must be some kind of pointer. Make a mental note of that, before going further...

Then, you also claim that your constructor is declared as follows:

```
Intersection(const glm::vec4& _point, const glm::vec4& _normal,
             Geometry* _geometry, const double _t)
```

That's what's shown in your your question. Now, ask yourself this: is the third parameter to this constructor a `double`, and the fourth parameter a some kind of a pointer, as you're constructing an instance of this class, in your `return` statement?

Comment: Yeah figures I wasn't checking the order I passed my arguments before assuming it had something to do with class inheritance...thanks